# Django install on a shared host, .htaccess help

Tags: python, .htaccess

I am trying to install Django on a shared host using the following instructions:
docs.google.com/View?docid=dhhpr5xs_463522g

My problem is with the following line on my root .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cgi-bin/wcgi.py/$1 [QSA,L]
```

When I include this line I get a 500 error with almost all of my domains on this account.

My cgi-bin directory is home/my-username/public_html/cgi-bin/

The wcgi.py file contains:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python

import os, sys

sys.path.insert(0, "/home/username/django/")
sys.path.insert(0, "/home/username/django/projects")
sys.path.insert(0, "/home/username/django/projects/newprojects")

import django.core.handlers.wsgi

os.chdir("/home/username/django/projects/newproject")    # optional
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "newproject.settings"

def runcgi():
    environ                      = dict(os.environ.items())
    environ['wsgi.input']        = sys.stdin
    environ['wsgi.errors']       = sys.stderr
    environ['wsgi.version']      = (1,0)
    environ['wsgi.multithread']  = False
    environ['wsgi.multiprocess'] = True
    environ['wsgi.run_once']     = True

    application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()

    if environ.get('HTTPS','off') in ('on','1'):
        environ['wsgi.url_scheme'] = 'https'
    else:
        environ['wsgi.url_scheme'] = 'http'

    headers_set  = []
    headers_sent = []

    def write(data):
        if not headers_set:
             raise AssertionError("write() before start_response()")

        elif not headers_sent:
             # Before the first output, send the stored headers
             status, response_headers = headers_sent[:] = headers_set
             sys.stdout.write('Status: %s\r\n' % status)
             for header in response_headers:
                 sys.stdout.write('%s: %s\r\n' % header)
             sys.stdout.write('\r\n')

        sys.stdout.write(data)
        sys.stdout.flush()

    def start_response(status,response_headers,exc_info=None):
        if exc_info:
            try:
                if headers_sent:
                    # Re-raise original exception if headers sent
                    raise exc_info[0], exc_info[1], exc_info[2]
            finally:
                exc_info = None     # avoid dangling circular ref
        elif headers_set:
            raise AssertionError("Headers already set!")

        headers_set[:] = [status,response_headers]
        return write

    result = application(environ, start_response)
    try:
        for data in result:
            if data:    # don't send headers until body appears
                write(data)
        if not headers_sent:
            write('')   # send headers now if body was empty
    finally:
        if hasattr(result,'close'):
            result.close()

runcgi()
```

Only I changed the "username" to my username...

Comment: But your shared host is able to run Python? I'm sure it is, just to confirm. Any chance of getting hold of Apache's `error.log` to see the exact error message? This may be hard without that information

Comment: don't seem to have access to error.log...my host does run Python (several modules)...maybe will check with them first about seeing the log??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I should be using fastcgi with my hosting service:

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```